# Is swipe to delete the only way of deleting a tableView row?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've been testing an app with people and after I tell them they can swipe to delete they find it intuitive but up front not everyone - in my experience at least - is savvy enough to figure it out.

Is there an alternative? I think ideally i'd like to have a little trash can or "x" on the the tableView cell that can be pressed to delete. But not sure that is easily implemented.

The first issue I encountered is I don't think I can drag an `IBOutlet` from a `TableViewCell` to the `UIViewController` where I have my table view.

And even if that is possible not sure how I would implement the below function when the delete button is clicked.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
```

So was just wondering if swipe to delete is my only option?

Thanks.

Comment: the important thing is you need to create a new class for your custom cell, and then you can set up the outlet and actions there and NOT as part of the UIViewController

Comment: Its very easy to implement it the "x" or any button-like delete. Although the "correct" way is swipe left. But the way i did it didn't include the function of `editingStyle`. I only had a button up right of the cell and when the user pressed it, i run a function that deletes the certain `indexPath.row` from the array of objects. Then refresh the table and it is deleted.

Comment: Hi @Russell. Yeah I've got a custom tableviewcell called CustomTableViewCell - but even with the delete button as an IBOutlet there i'm just not sure there's a function to implement to help with delete. For example the func tableView that i refer to in my original post is called automatically - i don't explicitly call it - when the delete button is clicked i'd have to call a method explicitly and i just don't know if that is the right way to do things. Although Magnas' and Kwnstantiinos suggestion might be adequate for me.

Comment: Yes! Of course! You can delete the cells from index path without a standard swipe gesture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this for implementing the "x" button on the the tableView cell:

```
protocol CustomCellDelegate {

    func removeButtonTappedOnCell(with indexPath: IndexPath)
}

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    var delegate: CustomCellDelegate?

    @IBOutlet weak var removeButton: UIButton!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    @IBAction func removeButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
        delegate?.removeButtonTappedOnCell(with: indexPath)
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, CustomCellDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.removeButton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }

    func removeButtonTappedOnCell(with indexPath: IndexPath) {
        modelArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .right)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is usually achieved by putting an 'Edit' button into one side of the Navigation Bar. The button puts the table into an edit mode that allows tapping of small, red delete buttons. Just another way to do the same thing, i.e. delete a row. Create a Master-Detail app from the iOS template and see how the button is created programmatically in the viewDidLoad method. Then look at the following methods that handle the deletion, whether initiated by a swipe or the Edit button.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        objects.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    } else if editingStyle == .insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }
}
```